# Copying object from one s3 compatible storage to other using AWS SDK for Java 2.x

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-java

Copying object from one s3 compatible storage to other using AWS SDK for Java 2.x. Can copyObject be used for this? copyObject is only working with in a single s3Client

tried using copyObject but not working. There is a work arround of downloading and uploading the object which i am not counting.

Answer (score 0):

No.

The `CopyObject` command only works 'within' one service. There is no standard for copying objects between storage services.

Also, credentials are created by a specific storage service and would only be accepted by that particular service. Credentials cannot be shared between storage services.

You will need to Download the objects from one service using their credentials and then Upload to the other service using their credentials.